# Python 3: multiprocessing, EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, eoferror

I wish to have a process continually monitoring RPi input, and set a variable (I have chosen a queue) to True or False to reflect the debounced value. Another process will then capture an image (from a stream).  I have written some code just to check I can get multiprocessing and signalling (the queue) working ok (I'm an amature coder...).

It all works fine with threading, but multiprocessing is giving an odd error. Specifically 'multiprocessing, EOFError: EOF when reading a line'. Code outputs:-

```
this computer has the following number of CPU's 6
OK, started thread on separate processor, now we monitor variable
enter something, True is the key word:
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "c:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Peter\Documents\NetBeansProjects\test_area\src\test4.py", line 16, in Wait4InputIsTrue
    ValueIs = input("enter something, True is the key word: ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

## This module monitors the 'port' (I am using the keyboard as an input):

```
#test4.py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Lock

def Wait4InputIsTrue(TheVar, TheLock):
    while True:
        sleep(0.2)
        TheLock.acquire()
        #try:
        ValueIs = input("enter something, True is the key word: ")
        #except:
        #    ValueIs = False
        if ValueIs == "True":
            TheVar.put(True)
            print("changed TheVar to True")
        TheLock.release()
```

## This module monitors the status, and acts on it:

```
#test5.py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock, cpu_count
    from time import sleep
    from test4 import Wait4InputIsTrue

    print("this computer has the following number of CPU's", cpu_count())
    LockIt = Lock()
    IsItTrue = Queue(maxsize = 3)

    Wait4 = Process(target = Wait4InputIsTrue, args = (IsItTrue, LockIt))
    Wait4.start()

    print("OK, started thread on separate processor, now we monitor variable")

    while True:
        if IsItTrue.qsize():
            sleep(0.1)
            print("received input from separate thread:", IsItTrue.get())
```

Note that I have tried adding a try: to the input statement in test4.py, in which case it keeps printing "enter something, True is the key word: " indefinitely, without a cr.

I added Lock in wild attempt to fix it, makes no difference

Anyone any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 9):

Your problem can be boiled down to a simpler script:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys

def worker():
    print("Got", repr(sys.stdin.read(1)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = mp.Process(target=worker)
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

When run, it produces

```
$ python3 i.py
Got ''
```

Reading zero bytes means the pipe is closed and `input(..)` turns that into an `EOFError` exception.

The `multiprocessing` module doesn't let you read `stdin`. That makes sense generally because mixing `stdin` readers from multiple children is a risky business. In fact, digging into the implementation, `multiprocessing/process.py` explicitly sets `stdin` to `devnull`:

```
                sys.stdin.close()
                sys.stdin = open(os.devnull)
```

If you are just using `stdin` for test, then the solution is simple: Don't do that! If you really need user input, life is quite a bit more difficult. You can use additional queues plus code in the parent to prompt users and get input.

Comment: I forgot I called `exit()` somewhere else as a crude debugging hack to get results... Kept wondering why I got this, but yeah, it's cause the process was being killed elsewhere.