# How to wait for an input for a set amount of time in python

Tags: python

In the code that I am writing in python, I check if there is an NFC tag at the reader with `id, text = reader.read()` how do I make it skip and do a different function if an NFC tag is not read in a set amount of time?

Thanks.

This is the code adapted form what you gave that i used to test it

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def NCFReader(info):
    info = input("Test: ")

def main():
# Motion is detected, now we want to time the function NCFReader
   info = None
   nfc_proc = Process(target=NCFReader, args=(info,))
   nfc_proc.start()
   nfc_proc.join(timeout=5)
   if nfc_proc.is_alive():
      nfc_proc.terminate()
      print("It did not complete")
      # PROCESS DID NOT FINISH, DO SOMETHING
   else:
      # PROCESS DID FINISH, DO SOMETHING ELSE
      print("It did complete")
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience setting a time limit on a function is surprisingly difficult.
It might seem as an over kill but the way I would do it is like this:
Say the function you want to limit is called `NFCReader` then

```
from multiprocessing import Process

# Create a process of the function
func_proc = Process(target=NFCReader)

# Start the process
func_proc.start()

# Wait until child process terminate or T seconds pass
func_proc.join(timeout=T)

# Check if function has finished and if not kill it
if func_proc.is_alive():
   func_proc.terminate()
```

You can read more about python Processes [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions)
Additionally Since you want to receive data from your Process you need to somehow be able to read a variable in one process and have it available in another, for that you can use the [Manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) object.

In your case you could to the following:

```
def NCFReader(info):
    info['id'], info['text'] = reader.read()

def main():
... SOME LINES OF CODE ...
# Motion is detected, now we want to time the function NCFReader
   info = Manager.dict()
   info['id'] = None
   info['text'] = None
   nfc_proc = Process(target=NCFReader, args=(info,))
   nfc_proc.start()
   nfc_proc.join(timeout=T)
   if nfc_proc.is_alive():
      nfc_proc.terminate()
      # PROCESS DID NOT FINISH, DO SOMETHING
   else:
      # PROCESS DID FINISH, DO SOMETHING ELSE
```

notice that the dictionary `info` is a dictionary that is shared among all Process, so if you would want to use it again make sure you reset it's values.

Hope this helps

Comment: I understand what you are saying but do not understand how to implement it, the reader is meant to check if a card is scanned after motion is detected if a card is scanned it will do one thing and I wish for it to do something else if one is not scanned in T seconds. How would I implement this? The code for reading a card from the scanner is ```id, text = reader.read()```    Thanks

Comment: I've edited the answer, tell me if it is more clear now

Comment: I have implemented it like you have said and have not been able to get it to work even with a simplified version just using a standard input any suggestions?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and where did it fail.

Comment: The code is in the initial post and it immediately runs the else statement

Comment: You are probably encountering an error which is causing the function to finish in less then 5 seconds, so the program is working as expected. To test it you can insert in your function `from time import sleep` and try `sleep(3)` and then `sleep(7)` and see the difference.

Comment: When running on my machine I encountered `EOFError: EOF when reading a line`, and I found a fix using `sleep` and followed the guidance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837544/python-3-multiprocessing-eoferror-eof-when-reading-a-line)