# Timed user input in Python

Tags: python, user-input, pygame-clock

I am trying to take user input in Python with a timer. I want the user to only have 10 seconds to enter something. However when 10 seconds is over the message "Time up!" is printed but the script does not stop.

```
import pygame
from threading import Thread

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
timee = 0
UIn=None

def func1():
    global timee
    global clock
    global UIn
    while True:
        milli = clock.tick()
        seconds = milli/1000

        timee=timee+seconds
        if(int(timee)==10):
            print("Time is over")
            quit()
        

def func2():
    global UIn
    print("Working")
    input("Press key:\t")


Thread(target=func1).start()
Thread(target=func2).start()
UIn=input("Press key:\t")
```

Comment: I have answered a similar question in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68968373/how-to-wait-for-an-input-for-a-set-amount-of-time-in-python/68968440#68968440) link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `Timer` class for this purpose

```
from threading import Timer

timeout = 10
t = Timer(timeout, print, ['Sorry, times up!'])
t.start()
prompt = "You have %d seconds to answer the question. What color do cherries have?...\n" % timeout
answer = input(prompt)
t.cancel()
```

Output:

```
You have 10 seconds to answer the question. What color do cherries have?
(After 10 seconds)
Sorry, times up!
```

Comment: And of course use a if ... else statement for the correct answer. So ... if answer == "red":  ... print("Correct") ... else: .... print("Try again")

Comment: Timer is a class, not a library. threading on the other hand is the library that contains it.

Comment: @COOL_IRON Thanks for the correction. I wanted to change and edit this but the site won't let me.

Comment: copy paste of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/12892026) .. ^^

Comment: The answer is not correct because the timer does not cancel the `input`. `Input` continues after the time is love. The question is how to "stop" `input` after 10 seconds.

Comment: @Rabbid76 yeah youre right, however the author mentioned that he does not want the script to stop, he might also mean the input by that

Comment: @matle No he does not. For this he put `input` in a separate thread (`func2`). The goal is to "terminate"  `func2`. Therefore the answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After giving it some thought and thanks to @Rabbid76 you probably want something like this (modified after the code from [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/12892026)):

```
import msvcrt
import time
import sys

class TimeoutExpired(Exception):
    pass

def input_with_timeout(prompt, timeout, timer=time.monotonic):
    """Timed input function, taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15533404/12892026"""
    sys.stdout.write(prompt)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    endtime = timer() + timeout
    result = []
    while timer() < endtime:
        if msvcrt.kbhit():
            result.append(msvcrt.getwche()) #XXX can it block on multibyte characters?
            if result[-1] == '\r':
                return ''.join(result[:-1])
        time.sleep(0.04) # just to yield to other processes/threads
    raise TimeoutExpired

# create a timed input object
try:
    answer = input_with_timeout("Give me an answer: ", 10)
except TimeoutExpired:
    print('\nSorry, times up')
else:
    print(f'\nYour answer was: {answer}')

# continue with code and verify the input
if answer:
    if answer == "yes":
        print("OK")
```

Comment: `msvcrt` is a Windows-only module, so anything based on it is platform-specific.